# Way to automate GetProto on all types with ProtoContract attribute

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I want to use reflection to look at all types in a .dll and generate the .proto file for any that have the ProtoContract attribute.  I'm going to use the .proto files to generate the C++ classes so my C# code can interop with some C++.  This code will look through a .dll to find the types with ProtoContract attribute, but I don't know how to dynamically pass in the type to GetProto().

```
//get assemblies in directory.
string file = @"C:\bungie\networking\shared\online\output\bin\Test\Xetrov\Xetrov.Core\Xetrov.Core.dll";
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (!type.IsClass || type.IsNotPublic) 
    {
        continue;
    }
    //Get all the attribute for the type
    object[] attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(true);
    //Look for the ProtoContract attribute
    if(attributes.Where(att => att is ProtoBuf.ProtoContractAttribute).Any())
    {
        // We have a type that protobuf can use, generate the .proto file
            // How to tell it what type T is??  can't use variable type
        string protoDefinition = ProtoBuf.Serializer.GetProto<T>();
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?  Or a better way to generate the .proto files for all types?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that GetProto is not yet re-implemented in v2, but will be when some time presents itself. So I'll assume we're talking about v1. As such, I suspect `MakeGenericMethod` is your best bet here:

```
// outside loop
var method = typeof(ProtoBuf.Serializer).GetMethod("GetProto");
...
// inside loop
var proto = untyped.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, null);
```

When I re-implement this in v2, it will also be available on the non-generic API (v2 uses non-generic as the core).